# Which is the correct preposition in "rejection of/to your gesture"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I recently read a sentence and I felt a bit confused about it.
The sentence was -

> His rejection of your gesture...

I felt it should have been -

> His rejection to your gesture...

Kindly clarify which is correct and why.

Comment: Can you write it as a complete sentence?

Answer (score 3):

No. *Rejection* takes *of*, not *to*.

Usually, when a verb that takes a direct object is nominalized, the noun takes *of*:

> He consumed the cake -> his consumption **of** the cake.

> We enjoyed the concert -> our enjoyment **of** the concert.

> I studied mathematics -> my study **of** mathematics.

There are exceptions to this, especially when it is a verb of motion:

> They approached the river -> their approach **to** the river

(but most verbs of motion require a preposition anyway).

When verbs that take an indirect object (with a preposition) are nominalized, they often take the same preposition:

> He interfered in the game -> his interference in the game

but I'm sure there are exceptions.

Comment: "Approach of the river" is also used, FWIW.

Comment: It's pretty marginal, @ThePhoton. In the iWeb corpus I find only 30 instances of "(possessive) approach of the" (which I've crafted to avoid other constructions), and I estimate that no more than half of them are this construction. This is against 5336 instances of "(possessive) approach to the"

Comment: I think it's because a river can have an approach, as in "the river's approach." I suspect this was more common in the days when rivers were the highways of commerce and extensively traveled: a river's approach was a place where goods could be loaded and dropped off. But now we tend to think of approaches from a land context, so an approach is an approach to a river.

Comment: I think the term "*nominalized*" might be unknown to many learners, at least in this sense, and a definition or explanation would improve this answer.